# How to hide scroll bar of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I m working on a `UICollectionView` class, and it will display the scroll bar when I scroll on the list, it's possible to hide scroll bar when scrolling?

Comment: thanks, i found solution myself, just showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Objective C:

```
 [collectionView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
 [collectionView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

Swift 3.0

```
colView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
colView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

From storyboard:

[image]

Comment: @Tejas Ardeshna, Can I make sticky horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 14):

in Swift:

```
collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

in Interface Builder: 
[image]

Comment: Can I make Sticky horizontal scroll bar?

Answer (score 3):

Option #1 (by code):

```
myCollectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
myCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

Option #2 (from storyboard):

Go to Attributes inspector > Uncheck "Show Horizontal Indicator" and "Show Vertical Indicator"